# jquery binding verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, binding, if-statement

Is there a way in jQuery to know if an element already has an event bound to the click or doubleclick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

From here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/

You can access all event handlers bound to an element (or any object) through jQuery’s event storage:

```
// List bound events:
console.dir( jQuery('#elem').data('events') );

// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});
```

Comment: yes. ...although it's not documented as officially part of the jQuery interface, so it may not be wise to rely on in an app you expect to run with a future version. Great for testing though.